# Add & remove route with low priority in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, vpn, powershell, routing

For a VPN network, to use non-VPN route as default, the article [Wireguard Split Tunnel By Adding Low Metric Route](https://asheroto.medium.com/split-tunneling-in-wireguard-on-windows-e2dfd86d5982) describes how to run a command in PowerShell to achieve this behaviour.

In PowerShell, it is required to run the following command to add a route with a low priority (interface metric)

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 IF $wgInterface.ifIndex metric 9999; Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $wgInterface.ifIndex -InterfaceMetric 9999;
```

And once finished / VPN is de-activated run:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 if $wgInterface.ifIndex metric 9999; Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $wgInterface.ifIndex -InterfaceMetric 9999;
```

What is the equivalent of these commands in Linux please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit: reworded & added link to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

To add the route:

```
sudo ip route add default metric 9999 via 0.0.0.0
```

To remove it again:

```
sudo ip route delete default metric 9999 via 0.0.0.0
```

where `default` corresponds to your `0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0` while the `via 0.0.0.0` corresponds to your third `0.0.0.0` (the next-hop address), so adapt accordingly if you don't really want to route everything to the all-zeroes address.

See `man ip-route` for details.